# laravel 5 blade how to redirect in blade template

Tags: redirect, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am a newbie in Laravel. I have view (blade template) file and wish to restrict access to this file only to logged in users. I know that this can be done like this...

```
@if(Auth::check())
// user is logged in. Display page
@else
// Now, user not logged in, how do i redirect to the login page
@endif
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Try this `@else 
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "{ url('/login') }"; //redirect
</script>`

Comment: We should not depend on javascript for such critical functionality.

Comment: Redirects should not be handled in the `view`; instead, either use `middleware` to check for auth status on multiple pages, or include that check someone in your controller and call `return redirect("/wherever")` when you need to.

Answer (score 3):

Views are not meant to control the request flow. This is done by the Controller.

In your `routes.php` file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
  Route::get('/','DashboardController@home');
});
```